# Where does the profile name on the Status Report come from?

Tags: 7, installation-profiles

When I click on *Reports > Status report*, the *Install profile* field says *Snrub (snrub-"1.1)* (with exactly one double quote). Where is this value defined?

Answer (score 2):

When the status report is rendered, profile info is retrieved from [`drupal_get_profile()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_profile/7.x) (by referencing the `install_profile` var) as well as [`system_get_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_get_info/7.x) to retrieve all the metadata properties (by referencing the `system` data table)

Answer (score 2):

The installation profile name given in the status report is output from [`system_requirements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.install/function/system_requirements/7.x), which uses the following code. (Note that code outputs the installation profile name and, between parentheses, the profile name returned from [`drupal_get_profile()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_get_profile/7.x) and its version. It's not the installation profile name that contains the installation profile version.)

```
// Display the currently active installation profile, if the site
// is not running the default installation profile.
$profile = drupal_get_profile();
if ($profile != 'standard') {
  $info = system_get_info('module', $profile);
  $requirements['install_profile'] = array(
    'title' => $t('Install profile'),
    'value' => $t('%profile_name (%profile-%version)', array(
      '%profile_name' => $info['name'],
      '%profile' => $profile,
      '%version' => $info['version'],
    )),
    'severity' => REQUIREMENT_INFO,
    'weight' => -9,
  );
}
```

In other places, Drupal shows the distribution name, which is returned from [`drupal_install_profile_distribution_name()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21install.inc/function/drupal_install_profile_distribution_name/7.x).

```
  // During installation, the profile information is stored in the global
  // installation state (it might not be saved anywhere yet).
  if (drupal_installation_attempted()) {
    global $install_state;
    return $install_state['profile_info']['distribution_name'];
  }
  else {
    $profile = drupal_get_profile();
    $info = system_get_info('module', $profile);
    return $info['distribution_name'];
  }
}
```

In both the case, that information is found in the .info file used from the installation profile / distribution. For example, the .info file for the [Panopoly](https://www.drupal.org/project/panopoly) distribution contains the following lines.

```
name = Panopoly
distribution_name = Panopoly
description = A magical framework for building Drupal products based on the Panels module
core = 7.x
exclusive = 1

; Drupal Core
dependencies[] = block
dependencies[] = menu
dependencies[] = image
dependencies[] = list
dependencies[] = number
dependencies[] = options
dependencies[] = path
dependencies[] = taxonomy
dependencies[] = search
dependencies[] = shortcut
dependencies[] = field
dependencies[] = field_ui
dependencies[] = file
dependencies[] = dblog
dependencies[] = update

; Panopoly Foundation
dependencies[] = panopoly_core
dependencies[] = panopoly_images
dependencies[] = panopoly_theme
dependencies[] = panopoly_magic
dependencies[] = panopoly_widgets
dependencies[] = panopoly_admin
dependencies[] = panopoly_users

; Panopoly Toolset
dependencies[] = panopoly_pages
dependencies[] = panopoly_search
dependencies[] = panopoly_wysiwyg

; Panopoly Recommended - Admin & UI
dependencies[] = navbar
dependencies[] = breakpoints
dependencies[] = backports
dependencies[] = simplified_menu_admin
dependencies[] = save_draft
dependencies[] = module_filter
dependencies[] = date_popup_authored
dependencies[] = views_ui

; Panopoly Recommended - Other
dependencies[] = devel
dependencies[] = distro_update
dependencies[] = uuid
dependencies[] = apps
```

If you are searching which file you need to edit to remove the double-quote character shown in the installation profile version, that is the .info file of the installation profile / distribution you used to install Drupal. Check the values given for the `version` key. The installation profile / distribution is using a wrong value for the version. (Actually, a distribution hosted on Drupal.org should not add the `version` key in its .info file, since that is automatically added from the packaging scripts running on Drupal.org. On Drupal.org, there isn't any [*Snrub*](https://www.drupal.org/project/snrub) distribution; I take it's a custom distribution hosted somewhere else, or build specifically for the site you are maintaining/developing.)